# Angular 2 Routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am new to angular2. I want to accomplish a task in which I have different headers and footers on different pages but don't know how to do this by using

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

as **router-outlet** just replace the component of that route. So what is the best way to get this. I searched a lot but found a pathetic solution that call header/footer in every single component.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on your requirements: If your header/footer is static but differs for some parts of your application you can use nested routing with the component router. The parent route determines the header/footer layout, the childroute the actual content.

If there is more logic involved, f.e. you need to determine the content in a more dynamic way you can create special components for the header and footer that determine the content using a service. (For example when your user is logged in vs. anonymous access.)

Comment: The thing is that in some part I don't want to have header/footer just a page for login. Once user logged in than we can add header/footer.

Comment: I suggest to use conditional rendering with *ngIf for that scenario. You can use an AuthService that provides the required state and use the *ngIf in your header and footer.

Comment: to be specific, I have a module let say auth in which I have three pages (sign-in, sign-up, forgot-pass). I defined routing in that module. So now when user visit some other URL let say abc.com/xyz which is other than these 3 pages (login/signup/forgot-pass), I want to shift the routing to that module that has xyz component in it and leave auth module.

Comment: I would use nested routing for this. So you have a top level router outlet in a template without header/footer. 
For the auth module you keep templates without header/footer, for the other module you use a template containing header and footer.

Comment: In that case don't keep header and footer into your parent view. Make a view and call it home. keep footer and header in this view and one router-outlet and load all the components in this only.
make another view and call it login and load as per your requirement on top level parent view

--APP
  |--MAIN (parent container)
        |--HOME (will contain all view)

Comment: @thomas can you please give an example of nested router as I am new in NG2 so don't have much idea of it.

Comment: I strongly suggest to learn the fundamentals of routing using the tutorial. You can find an extensive description including examples and explanation at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html (you are looking for 'child routes').

Answer (score 1):

It is really simple to achieve your task. Do not add anything in the HTML file in which you are using top most router-outlet. Now every page you will load in parent router outlet will cover whole page so you can design every view as per your requirement.

In case someone need something common throughout the application, put that common elements on the same file which contains your top most router-outlet.

Answer (score 0):

In that case don't keep header and footer into your parent view. Make a view and call it home. keep footer and header in this view and one router-outlet and load all the components in this only.
make another view and call it login and load as per your requirement on top level parent view

```
--APP(main)
  |--MAIN (parent container)
        |--HOME (will contain all view)
              |--CHILD (parent will be home)
        |--LOGIN (Parent Will be main)
```